# All existing plans or all of existing plans?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, all-of

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “of ” necessary in “all of ”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80412/is-of-necessary-in-all-of)

Which one of the following is correct (or preferred if both are grammatical)?

> - All existing plans.
> - All of existing plans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say either

> ... all existing plans

or

> ... all of the existing plans

but not

> ... all of existing plans