# The use of the definite article in a definite context

Tags: articles

We use the definite article to talk about specific objects, but does the same logic apply when we speak about a set of objects that is restricted by another definite noun phrase:

1) All (the) plates in the kitchen were broken

2) (The) plates in the kitchen were broken

3) All (the) cars in Italy are expensive

4) (The) cars in Italy are expensive

5) I drank all (the) water from the tank

6) I drank (the) water from the tank

**"Plates"** is restricted by **"the kitchen"**

**"Cars"** is restricted by **"Italy"**

**"Water"** is restricted by **"the tank"**

Would dropping "(the)" in the above examples affect the meaning ?

I have seen example such as "*all members of the group*" instead of "*all the members of the group*". Both seem OK, but if anyone requested an explanation, I wouldn't be able to give one.

Comment: I think this kind of question belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Note that ***all members / all the members / all of the members** [of the group]* are all perfectly valid, and effectively mean the same thing.

Comment: ...but you might want to check out [Difference between 'all' and 'all the'.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4863/difference-between-all-and-all-the) Also [“All our X” vs. “all of our X”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65650/all-our-x-vs-all-of-our-x) and [Is “of ” necessary in “all of ”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80412/is-of-necessary-in-all-of)

Comment: Thank you, FumbleFingers, I'll check them out right away!

Comment: If those ELU answers don't resolve your problem, have a look at these questions on ELL - [“All” vs. “All the”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67267/all-vs-all-the) and [“All of the …” or “ All the … ”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/all-of-the-or-all-the) and [What's the Difference between “all” and “all the”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/146871/whats-the-difference-between-all-and-all-the)

Comment: Also please take a look at [the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9LYu.jpg) from Raymond Murphy's "English Grammar in Use" (Unit 88).

Comment: Your analysis leads to a false conclusion. The fact that something is a specific place does not force the use of the definite article: ***A*** *plate **in the kitchen** was broken.* You can also simply say *Plates are broken*. The fact that there is a specific context makes no difference to the existence of an article, or to the type used.

Comment: ambitious_ph1lologist, Jason Bassford, thank you for help! When İ say "İ drank water from the tank" does the sentence have a nuance "İ drank water, not wine, nor soda"?